# from table to (image) array using vectorized operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

Is there a way to get data from a table e.g.

```
axis0  axis1  value
0      0      2
1      1      1
0      1      3
```

into an (image) array

```
[[2 3]
[nan 1]]
```

using vectorized operations or something like that? And yes, in the data some points are missing and there should then be nan or equivalent.

Now I am doing that with a for loop inserting values into an array having all values nan but when there are more data, it is quite slow to process the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Create a empty array with the desired shape then update the values in the arr using the information from dataframe

```
x, y = df[['axis0', 'axis1']].max() + 1
arr = np.full((x, y), np.nan)
arr[df['axis0'], df['axis1']] = df['value']
```

Option 2: Pivot the dataframe on axis columns then reindex to ensure the proper shape then convert to numpy

```
x, y = df[['axis0', 'axis1']].max() + 1
(
    df
    .pivot(index='axis0', columns='axis1', values='value')
    .reindex(index=range(x), columns=range(y))
    .to_numpy()
)
```

Result

```
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [nan,  1.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

 data = np.array([
    [0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 3]
])

axis0 = data[:, 0]
axis1 = data[:, 1]
values = data[:, 2]

rows = np.max(axis0) + 1
cols = np.max(axis1) + 1
   
result = np.full((rows, cols), np.nan)

result[axis0, axis1] = values
print(result)
```

output:-

```
 [[ 2.  3.]
 [nan  1.]]
```

extract  `axis0` , `axis1` and `values` from data.then calculate the dimensions of the resulting array, then use `np.full` to create an empty array filled with `NaN`. then fill in values in the empty array.